# Squid configure failed with Invalid configuration `—': machine `—' not recognized on config.sub

Tags: linux, configure, squid, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to compile squid on raspberry PI4 Linux. (Since the regular squid doesn't have sslbump by default).
There are many great guides out there to configure Squid with SSL, but non of them address the problem of "unknown machine" problem with PI
I downloaded the sources for squid-5.0.4.

The configure command is ran, and the error i get is:

```
sudo ./configure — with-openssl — enable-ssl-crtd --disable-arch-native


configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: —
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: —
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '0' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for —-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for —-g++... no
checking for —-c++... no
checking for —-gpp... no
checking for —-aCC... no
checking for —-CC... no
checking for —-cxx... no
checking for —-cc++... no
checking for —-cl.exe... no
checking for —-FCC... no
checking for —-KCC... no
checking for —-RCC... no
checking for —-xlC_r... no
checking for —-xlC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `—': machine `—' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash cfgaux/config.sub — failed
```

when i run the **config.guess** to check my system architecture the result is:

```
$ sudo bash +x cfgaux/config.sub armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

I tried it on various distributions - squid3, squid4,squid5 and the error is always the same.

trying to understand if there's a missing package i need to detect the machine properly , or just a workaround to get it compiled.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I just found that I can tweak the configure command with **--host** and **--target**  to specify my machine, which have resolved the problem for me.
I was able to build the package successfully.

To Configure it, the running command is:

```
sudo ./configure  --host=armv7l --target=armv7l --enable-ssl-crtd  --with-openssl
```

I hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this command in your config it `--build=x86_64`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.